Concrete example of a non-singular cubic surface S in char 3 with the 'other' cuspidal curve on it
I'm working with a high-school student through Reid's proof of the 27 lines on a nonsingular cubic surface, and we just looked at the classification of singular cubic plane curves over algebraically closed fields. In characteristic 3, if I'm not mistaken, there are two inequivalent options for cuspidal cubics: $y^2 = x^3$ and $y^2 + x^2y = x^3$. My student wanted to know if the second case actually happens, that is, is there a nonsingular cubic surface $S = (f(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3) = 0)$ in $\mathbb{P}^3_k$, $\mathrm{char}(k)=3$, with a point $p\in S$ such that $T_pS\cap S$ is described by $y^2 + x^2y = x^3$? I'm not an algebraic geometer, so I don't know the techniques one would use to construct such a thing. Ideally one should just write down the homogeneous cubic polynomial $f$ describing $S$, and a point $p$ such that $T_pS$ is $(x_3=0)$ and then in the affine chart $x_2\neq 0$ we have $f(x,y,1,0) = y^2 + x^2y - x^3$.
[I have a secondary query, which is why does Reid assume all cuspidal cubic curves are of the form $y^2=x^3$? Am I missing something? There's an exercise that assumes char≠2; did I miss another disclaimer somewhere?]

The approach you suggest to "just write down" a cubic with the right properties works fine in practice. In more detail, what you need is a cubic polynomial in $x,y,z,w$ such that:

putting $z=1$ and $w=0$ gives your desired equation;

putting $z=1$ gives something with linear term equal to $w$;

the resulting surface is nonsingular.


The first condition implies in particular that $p=[0,0,1,0]$ is a point on the surface, and the second condition then implies that the tangent plane at $p$ is just given by $w=0$.
So you can take
$$F(x,y,z,w) = y^2z+x^2y-x^3-z^2w-(ax+by+cz)w^2-dw^3$$
and verify that for a "suitably general" choice of coefficients $a,b,c,d$ the resulting surface is nonsingular. You can even choose $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb F^3$: for example I took $a=c=d=1$ and $b=2$ and got a nonsingular surface.

Well, if I knew how to even start, I wouldn't ask here :-) There's all kinds of little tricks I see people using in lecture notes I'm consulting that do not naturally occur to me, and which must seem very obvious to those in the field.

All I was getting at in my first sentence is that your idea to "just write down" the cubic you want is the right approach, rather than using anything fancier. Anyway, I hope this helps.

I agree, but I didn't know how to actually do it! So thanks for at least putting me on the right track.

Your $y^2$ term cannot be correct, I guess it's meant to be something like $(z+ew)y^2$? And perhaps $e=0$ works...

Just checking: this is in characteristic = 3, right? char k = deg f here, which makes things weird...

Whoops, I dropped a $z$ from the first term --- now fixed. Yes, this is in characteristic 3.
